# Drupal 7, Domain Access, and SSO (Single Sign-On)

Tags: drupal-7, single-sign-on, drupal-domain-access

Has anyone made any headway with coming up with a single sign on solution
with Domain access to date for Drupal 7? I've been looking closely at two old
modules, one no longer maintained (SSO for D6) and one still maintained (CAS). I've also read that SAML might be a key to unlocking this, but am uncertain. 
Facebook's FBConnect might be another option too or another way could be integrating OpenID from what I've read, and experienced on StackOverflow's sub sites.

I know that OpenID can do this since we are logged into all of *Overflows sub sites at the same time using one login. The question is how does it cross DNS servers? Does it handshake with one half of a matching hash? I cannot find any documentation on this, so am at a loss.

So, are there any solutions that are known to date, or information on what to start
looking into? I think I've made a  good point at the possibilities. I read this thread, [Domain Access SSO](http://bleen.net/blog/domain-access-sso) but am uncertain to what version it pertains to (Drupal. DA, SSO or otherwise). It looks like the "Solution" is to create a master table set with users and permissions, then share those across the domains? How might this work if there are already multiple sites created under Domain Access? Would you clone and rebuild the entire installation, or would you need to start from scratch? It really raises more questions than answers. I contacted the author with no response, so the questions still stand.

Any opinions out there on the who what or why would be greatly appreciated, I just need a start point to get the ball rolling. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the Domain Access SSO article mentioned in the original question.  I don't recall being contacted about it, but then again I recently learned that my "contact" page on bleen.net hasn't been working in a while... but anyway, here is a bit of info:

That post referred to Drupal 6, SSO Module 6.x-1.0-rc1, and Domain Access module 6.x-2.0 (I think). That solution basically revolves around creating two separate drupal installs, one the master and one the client (there can be multiple clients). Basically, what happens is the necessary user tables for all teh clients are pointed instead to the master. In doing so, the master becomes (essentially) a shell site that does nothing but hold and verify user data.

Hope that makes sense and/or helps... to be honest i havent looked at that code in a long while now.

Answer (score 1):

SAML is a good option.  Check this module to integrate  it with drupal:

http://drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth

If you need a demo with this plugin working check [this](http://apps.uniquid.yaco.es/drupal).

Comment: Will this module work in collaboration with Domain Access though?